# Discord.py как сделать комманду в два слова?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Я б хотел бы назватт комманду в два слова типо что бв можно было написать -Lhelp commands, и он отсылал бы текст но я не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: вся информация есть тут: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: если уж лень читать документацию то вот: https://qna.habr.com/q/882239

Answer (score 0):

Не могу сказать как это сделать красиво но можешь сделать костыль:

```
@bot.command()
async def Lhelp(ctx, is_commands):
    if is_commands == 'commands':
        #Твои команды здесь
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Замените поалуйста картинку кодом как текст.